# Windows XP final release

Tags: windows-xp

Where from I get the final release of Windows XP, including all updates?

Comment: Do you want to pay for it?

Comment: I need a trial version with SP3 and all other updates.

Comment: 8 years of Windows XP and you need to try it out? ;-)

Comment: I am now using Linux.

Comment: What specifically do you need it for? If your using Linux, is there nothing (even on Wine) that could help you?

Comment: Woah, when did they finish Windows XP? The version I'm using still has a few rough edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only available trial that I know of is the [Windows 7 Release Candidate](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/download.aspx), keeping in mind that:

- Downloads will be available until August 20, 2009
- The RC will expire on June 1, 2010.

There are not trials for XP or for Vista.

Comment: You are able to install and run windows XP (or Vista) for 30 days without activating, you know... I think that counts as *trial*.

Comment: Yes, but you can't _download_ them. Not legally, anyway.

Comment: Unless your a TechNet or MSDN subscriber

Comment: In which case you probably have enough money to just buy XP, even if you decide you don't want to use it in the end.

Comment: while you don't have to activate it for 30 days you will still need a valid product key...

Answer (score 13):

You buy it from a shop and then install it and run Windows update.

Comment: Having tried this, I can say that most shops no longer carry XP. Even if you ask nicely. I know Best Buy didn't when I really needed it in a pinch ("broke" someone's home computer, with SP3 actually). Some online stores carry XP, but usually not XP SP3.

Answer (score 9):

The normal procedure would be:

- install Windows XP from your installation medium (CD-ROM for example)
- apply the latest service pack (currently that's Service Pack 3)
- run Windows Update and apply all patches

Regarding patching/updating Windows: there is a nice solution if you have to do this for multiple computers and want to minimize your download time and volume. *heise security*, a website of a German magazine publisher, has a nice, free solution for packaging Windows Updates:

[DIY Service Pack - Installing Windows updates without an internet connection](http://www.h-online.com/security/Do-it-yourself-Service-Pack--/features/80682)

> Looking for manageable Windows updates
>   even without an internet connection?
>   Our offline update 3.0 script
>   collection downloads the entire body
>   of updates for Windows 2000, XP or
>   Server 2003 from Microsoft's servers
>   in one fell swoop and then uses them
>   to create patch packages on CD, DVD or
>   USB stick. Those in turn allow you to
>   update as many PCs as desired.

Answer (score 8):

You can also download all the updates and [slipstream](http://www.google.be/search?q=slipstream+windows+xp) them together with your original CD into a new ISO file.

Answer (score 7):

If you are a [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com) subscriber you can download the latest SP3 slip-streamed version from the respective download sites.

Comment: Woot for couple-thousand-dollar solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to do the slipstreaming of SP3, you can also use this [Elder Geek's guide](http://www.theeldergeek.com/slipstreamed_xpsp3_cd_final.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You determine the final release by looking at the [roadmap](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/lifecycle/servicepacks.mspx). It also links you to the service pack to download (SP3). Since you cannot buy it in stores anymore, you must copy someone else's disk. If the disk does not include SP3, you must go through a [slipstreaming](http://lifehacker.com/386526/slipstream-service-pack-3-into-your-windows-xp-installation-cd) dance. Once you have this Win XP with SP3 disk you can use it to install on the intended machine *provided* you have an activation key. You can still buy activation keys by going through the [Microsoft Genuine Advantage](http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/products/WindowsXP.aspx?displaylang=en) thing, or by calling them, if that's what you actually need. They're not all talk, they have an accounts receivable department.

If you are in college, inquire with you're college first. They might have paid the Microsoft tax as part of your tuition which entitles you to certain things, possibly a license to windows and office. Probably free versions of Visual Studio and other products.

Now, although most stores you walk into don't carry it anymore, you can get it online. Such as from [NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116515).